# Functions are not defined (Multiple function calls) - React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to call two functions on Button click. But it is every time giving me the error stating 'func1' is not defined and 'func2' is not defined. Also, I'm calling a method present in the Parent component from the child component, but it gives me an error stating 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression'.

I tried to call a function on button click and that function has two functions which need to be called but still having the issue.

This is my Parent component code:

```
class App extends React.Component{
updateCount = () => {
        count++;
        this.setState({counter: count})
    }

return (
                            <CardComponent
                                handle={allData.handle}
                                avatar={allData.avatar}
                                source={allData.source}
                                content={allData.content}
                                timestamp={this.getDate(allData.timestamp)}
                                meta={allData.meta} 
                                triggerParentUpdate={this.updateCount} 
                                btnMessage={btnMessage}
                                btnColor={btnColor}
                            />
                        );
}
```

This is my child component code

```
class CardComponent extends React.Component{
onClick(event){
  func1();
  func2();
}

func1(){
  {this.props.triggerParentUpdate};
}
func2(){
   console.log("Hello World...");
}

render(){
   return(
      <button onClick={this.onClick} type="button"}></button>
   );
}
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but it should call those two function when a button is clicked. Also when func1() function is called it should call the function present in parent component.

Comment: It looks like you have several problems with calling functions throughout your code, not just the `func1` and `func2` calls.

Comment: There are no variables `func1` and `func2` available in the scope of `onClick`. Methods are not magically defined inside other methods (which you seem to know since you are using `this.onClick` insider `render` and not just `onClick`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your `onClick` method to an arrow function and call `func1` and `func1` via `this`;

```
onClick = event => {
    this.func1();
    this.func2();
}
```

A more complete example of how your `CardComponent` could look:

```
class CardComponent extends React.Component{
    onClick = event => {
        this.func1();
        this.func2();
    }
    func1 = () => {
        this.props.triggerParentUpdate();
    }
    func2() {
        console.log("Hello World...");
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.onClick} type="button">Click Me</button>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends on how their build tool chain is setup. Or are class properties picked up by `preset-env` now? *edit:* Since they are using `updateCount = () => {...}` in the other component I guess everything is configured correctly. It would still be useful to explain what the issue is and why this solves it.

Comment: Thanks @wdm this worked for me. But when I'm trying to call a function present in Parent component it's giving me an error stating 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression'. Any suggestions for that. I'm using {this.props.triggerParentUpdate} this to call a method in parent class

Comment: @allanshivji see edits i was making as your were commenting :D

Comment: @allanshivji: `{this.props.triggerParentUpdate}` is not a function call. Functions are called by putting `()` after a function reference, e.g. `foo()`. `{...}` here denotes a *block* and is unnecessary (`{foo()}` is the same as `foo()` in this context).

Answer (score 0):

A few thing you need to do to fix your code:

Change Card component to:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Card extends React.Component {
  onClick(event) {
    this.func1();
    this.func2();
  }

  func1() {
    this.props.triggerParentUpdate
  }

  func2() {
    console.log("Hello World...");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.onClick} type="button">CLick</button>
    )
  }
}
```

Because you are accessing this in your `onClick` method, you need to bind that method. See the changes:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Card extends React.Component {
  onClick(event) {
    this.func1();
    this.func2();
  }

  func1() {
    this.props.triggerParentUpdate();
  }

  func2() {
    console.log("Hello World...");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={(event) => this.onClick(event)} type="button">CLick</button>
    )
  }
}
```